# Need some help understanding basics about JS module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, closures

I am trying to organize my code using the revealing module pattern.
I have a very basic question about how to set up a setter method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var designs = (function() {  
        var curRow,  
            setCurRow = function(val) {  
                curRow = val;  
            },
            initTable = function() {  
                setCurRow(0);
            };
        return {
            curRow : curRow,
            setCurRow : setCurRow,
            initTable : initTable
        }
    }) ();  
    designs.initTable();  
    designs.setCurRow(someNewVal);
    console.log(designs.curRow);
});
```

The problem is that i dont get the someNewVal in the console output, I get `undefined` instead! I have a feeling I am doing something pretty silly here.

Comment: You get `undefined`, because you haven't defined `someNewVal`. Nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also solve this in another way by understanding the scopes of the variables and functions involved.

When you return your object constructor `{ curRow: curRow ... }`, that just initializes the object member named `curRow` to the *value* of the variable `curRow` in the scope of the anonymous function; it doesn't create any persistent connection between them.

Once the anonymous function returns, calling `designs.setCurRow` is updating the `curRow` variable in that scope exactly as you expect, but that variable is now totally inaccessible to the outside world -- there is no connection between it and the `curRow` member of designs.

You can solve this by making the `setCurRow` method operate on `this.curRow`, as in the other solutions. In that case you don't need to make `curRow` a variable in the original scope, since it's entirely unused. The other solution is to add a 'getter' method to your current one:

```
var designs = (function() {  
    var curRow,  
    setCurRow = function(val) {  
        curRow = val;  
    },
    getCurRow = function() {
        return curRow;
    },
    initTable = function() {  
        setCurRow(0);
    };
    return {
        getCurRow : getCurRow,
        setCurRow : setCurRow,
        initTable : initTable
    };
}) ();  
designs.initTable();  
designs.setCurRow(someNewVal);
console.log(designs.getCurRow());
```

Because `getCurRow` and `setCurRow` are *functions* that are closed in the scope containing the variable `varRow`, they can reach back into that scope and access and change variables that are only accessible within it.

In this case making `curRow` a member of the object you return is probably simpler, but the other way is useful too since you can use it to create effectively [private members and methods](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much this is exactly the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want an object, not a module:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var designs = {
            setCurRow: function(val) {  
                this.curRow = val;  
            },
            initTable: function() {  
                this.setCurRow(0);
            },
            curRow: 0
    };  
    designs.initTable();  
    designs.setCurRow(someNewVal);
    console.log(designs.curRow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setCurRow` sets the value of the variable `curRow` after `designs.curRow` has already been set. Consider something like this:

```
var a = 1;
b = a; // sets b = a = 1
b = 2; // sets b = 2; leaves a = 1
```

Your code is doing the same thing, but with object-properties and setter methods to make it look complicated. :-)

Comment: So how would I change my code to be able to change the value of curRow?

Answer (score 0):

As ruakh pointed out, you never re-assign `curRow` on the returned object, so it is always the default value.  Change it to:

```
setCurRow = function(val) {  
    this.curRow = curRow = val;  
},
```

And everything should work`*`.

`*` At least mostly - you won't be able to use `call` and `apply` on `setCurRow` (or pass it to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` without binding it first to your object (`designs`), since `this` is bound at call time in JavaScript.